# MQTT Topic length

Tags: mqtt, stm32, sim800, hivemq

As I intend to use an MQTT Topic of length 26 characters to publish, it does not publish to the broker. But I can use an MQTT Topic of length 25 characters to publish by reducing one character from the same topic. Is there a specific limitation on the topic length and if there is how long can it be?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the MQTT [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718039) (assumed v3.1.1 but hasn't changed in v5) the size of the topic length is represented by 2 bytes so can be up to 65,535 chars.

Any limit you are hitting is most likely to be a constraint of the MQTT client you are using. I suggest you check the broker logs (probably in verbose mode) to see what if anything is actually being sent by the client with the longer topic.

Comment: Or use wireshark, assuming that you are doing plaintext MQTT.